# Setting connection properties on the URL object

Tags: java

**Question:** Is there a way to set the connection properties on the `URL` object?

---

**Background:**
We are connecting to a remote server that requires certain connection properties to be set (e.g. User-Agent but certain proprietary properties as well).  We are currently using the `setRequestProperty` method on the `URLConnection` object for this purpose.  So far so good.  Now we want to use an API that requires the `URL` object.  We have not been able to figure out how to set the connection request properties on a `URL` object.  As a result the remote server is rejecting the API call with response code `403`.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

FYI `urlConnObject.getURL()` did **not** do the trick and the server rejected the call with `403` error code.

Comment: `URL` does not have connection properties, but `URLConnection` does. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have, including the "API" you are trying to use. Also check the documentation of the API you are using on how to change request properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Is there a way to set the connection properties on the URL object?

Answer: There is no way.

A Java `URL` or `URI` object does not have connection properties, or any way to represent them.

Connection properties are supported by the APIs that actually establish a connection; e.g. `java.net.URLConnection` and its subtypes, Java 11+ `java.net.http.HttpClient` and various 3rd-party HTTP client libraries.

---

Here are a couple of ideas that may help:

- You could construct a `Map<URL, Map<String, String>>` that associates URLs with sets of connection properties, by that is rather inflexible and there is potential for memory leaks if the map is long-lived.
- You could create a custom class that represents "target" web object as a URL and a collection of connection properties and ... other relevant things.

The best solution will depend on what you are *actually* trying to achieve, and your application's internal architecture.